# The variable declared using 'this' or "var Vm = this" in controller is not reflecting the value when accessed using directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, controller, directive

I am trying out directives in angular. I was trying to use variables with values inside a directive which is declared using `this` or `var Vm = this`. But the value of the variable is not showing.

When I try to call the variable inside the directive. This happens when scope: `{}`is called under the directive declaration.

I am attaching the code of the controller and the directive:

**controller (js code)**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('serviceApp')
    .controller('ServiceCtrl', ServiceCtrl);

  ServiceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'serviceService'];

  function ServiceCtrl($scope, serviceService) {

    var Vm = this;

    Vm.square = function() {
      Vm.result = serviceService.square(Vm.number);
    };

    // $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    // $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
  }
})();
```

**directive code**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('serviceApp')
    .directive('sampleDir', sampleDir);

  function sampleDir() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {

      },
      templateUrl: "views/directive-template.html"
    };
  }
})();
```

When I use the result variable under the html template by calling it from the controller, it is displaying the value.

```
<div ng-controller="ServiceCtrl as ser">
  <label for="num">Enter the number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="num" ng-model="ser.number" ng-keyup="ser.square();">
  <button>x2</button>

  <p>Result: {{ser.result}}</p>

  <div>
    <sample-dir></sample-dir>
  </div>
</div>
```

template of directive

```
<p>Square of the number is <strong>{{ser.result}}</strong></p>
```

Please, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `scope: {}`, it creates an `isolated scope`(which means no access to parent scopes) and does not have any items in it. So you can't access the `result` in the `controller`.

In your case you can use `scope: true` and use your template like you did it or change the scope to this

```
scope: {
   result: '='
};
```

and in the template

```
<sample-dir result='ser.result'></sample-dir>
```

This will be the directive's template.

```
<p>Square of the number is <strong>{{result}}</strong></p>
```

For more see here **[Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**

**This is a kindly changed example with `scope: {}`**

```js
angular.module('serviceApp', []).controller('ServiceCtrl', ServiceCtrl);

ServiceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ServiceCtrl($scope) {

 var Vm = this;
  Vm.number = 0;

 Vm.square = function () {
    Vm.result = Vm.number * Vm.number;
 };

 // $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
 // $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
 }



 angular .module('serviceApp').directive('sampleDir', sampleDir);

  function sampleDir() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        result: '='
      },
      template: '<p>Square of the number is <strong>{{result}}</strong></p>'
    };
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='serviceApp' ng-controller="ServiceCtrl as ser">
<label for="num">Enter the number: </label>
 <input type="text" id="num" ng-model="ser.number" ng-keyup="ser.square();"> 
 <button>x2</button>

 <p>Result: {{ser.result}}</p> 


 <div>
 <sample-dir result='ser.result'></sample-dir> 

 </div>
```

**This is a kindly changed example with `scope: true`**

```js
 angular.module('serviceApp', []).controller('ServiceCtrl', ServiceCtrl);

    ServiceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function ServiceCtrl($scope) {

     var Vm = this;
      Vm.number = 0;

     Vm.square = function () {
        Vm.result = Vm.number * Vm.number;
     };

     // $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
     // $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
     }



     angular .module('serviceApp').directive('sampleDir', sampleDir);

      function sampleDir() {
        return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope: true,
          template: '<p>Square of the number is <strong>{{ser.result}}</strong></p>'
        };
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='serviceApp' ng-controller="ServiceCtrl as ser">
  <label for="num">Enter the number: </label>
  <input type="text" id="num" ng-model="ser.number" ng-keyup="ser.square();"> 
  <button>x2</button>

  <p>Result: {{ser.result}}</p> 


  <div>
    <sample-dir></sample-dir> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the result in the scope like this :

**directive code**

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('serviceApp')
    .directive('sampleDir', sampleDir);

    function sampleDir() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                result: "="  // added this line
            },
            templateUrl: "views/directive-template.html"
        };
    }
})();
```

**Html code**

```
<div ng-controller="ServiceCtrl as ser">
    <label for="num">Enter the number: </label>
    <input type="text" id="num" ng-model="ser.number" ng-keyup="ser.square();"> 
    <button>x2</button>

    <p>Result: {{ser.result}}</p> 
</div>

<div>
    <sample-dir result="ser.result"></sample-dir> // pass result here
</div>
```

**Directive html**

```
<p>Square of the number is <strong>{{result}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: Thank you guys :) I had called multiplication in a service and injected here to the controller, so, I think it confused u people, it worked I tried with other example too.

Comment: I am newly posting my issues on this. I have tried the answers that was answered for my issue :) :)

Comment: you'll end up with negative reputation ;)

Comment: Hi Tom Shen, I am new to stackoverflow with respect to posting my queries, I was not aware of this reputations and all, now I am coming to know about that. Thank you for your suggestion :)